# An $\mathsf{SL(n,F)}$ decomposition problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-groups

Given  $n\times n$ square matrix $A\in\Bbb F^{n\times n}_{}$ where $\Bbb F$ is a field is there an easy way to test there is NO decomposition $A=B+C+D$ where $B,C,D\in\mathsf{SL}(n,{\Bbb F})$ are distinct?

Comment: What's an example of a matrix for which there is no decomposition?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}111\\

100\\

100\end{bmatrix}$

satisfies.

Comment: matrices $B,C,D$ are distinct.

Comment: The problem is clearly invariant under multiplying $A$ from left or right by an $\mathrm{SL}(n,F)$ matrix, hence you can reduce it to the case where $A$ is diagonal.

Comment: How do you know this for your example?

Comment: The distinctness makes it much harder, otherwise it is a relatively simple algebraic problem.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Indeed. More precisely, we can reduce to either the case of a diagonal matrix $(t,1,1,\dots,1)$ with $t\neq 0$, or a diagonal matrix $(1,1,\dots,1,0,0,\dots,0)$ (or, in other words, for a matrix $A$, it only depends on the pair $(\det(A),\mathrm{rank}(A))$).

Comment: @Turbo no, I said what I said, which is distinct

Comment: Exercise: In size 2: if the field has at least 3 elements, then we can get all matrices, and if the field is $\mathbf{F}_2$ we precisely get the non-invertible matrices.

Comment: I said that if we determine which among these special diagonal matrices are a sum of three distinct det-1 matrices, then we have solved the general case.

Comment: @Ycor So we have only $(|\Bbb F|-1)+n$ cases to consider right?

Comment: Yes... anyway if you do it in dimension 2 all cases of determinant $\neq 0,1$ can be done in one step.